# Jackson derived property with getter only gives com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

My class looks like this

```
class Foo {
     int x;

     public void setX(int x){
        this.x=x;
     }

     public int getX(){
       return x;
     }
     public int getDoubleX(){
         return x*2;
     }
}
```

When serializing the class to JSON using Jackson I get an error:

```
**JSON parse error: Unrecognized field "doubleX"**
```

I tried annotating with `@JsonGetter` but that did not work.

The only thing that seems to work with Jackson is to create a setter that does nothing and annotate it with `@JsonIgnore`.

Comment: But do you want to ignore it or include to `JSON` result?

Comment: include to JSON, but I don't need the setter.

Comment: Which version of library do you use? It should work without any extra annotations. Do you want to serialise or deserialise `JSON` or both?

Comment: 2.9.8 BOM (being used to serialize objects from / to controllers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@JsonIgnoreProperties` annotation:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class Foo
```

It should allow to serialise all `getters` and skip unknown during deserialisation.

Comment: Is this bad practice? Does it open me up to other issues if unknown properties are included?

Comment: @qwerty, from documentation: "Property that defines whether it is ok to just ignore any unrecognized properties during deserialization". It is class level property and it controls behavior only for given class. If your class is not complicated and you can test all cases and for all cases you have desired output you can treat it as safe. Since version [2.6](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnoreProperties.html) you have 2 extra properties: `allowGetters` and `allowSetters`. You can use them if you want to be more precise.

Comment: @qwerty, In answer I mentioned about `ignoreUnknown` because it works for older version as well. You can try to test all kind of configurations and pick the best for you.

Comment: @JsonIgnoreProperties(allowSetters=true,ignoreUnknown=true) - this worked