# @Transient method causes error "Unrecognized field (…), not marked as ignorable"

Tags: json, jackson, resteasy, transient

I am serializing a Java class to transfer it to my client as a JSON object. The class has various attributes and a set of `@Transient` methods that combine a subset of those properties. The transient methods do not have any variable to back them up.

```
public class Person {
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;

  public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
  }

  public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
  }

  public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }

  public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
  }

  @Transient
  public String getFullName() {
    return firstName + " " + lastName;
  }
}
```

When reading an object from server, this works fine. When I try to save the JSON object, however, it causes this error for the transient methods:

> "Unrecognized field (...), not marked as ignorable"

**I do not want to introduce variables for the transient properties, still I want to transfer the return value of the transient methods from server to client. How can I achieve that?**

What I tried is this, but I'm not sure, if I fully understood the idea of the `@Json*` annotations:

```
@Transient
@JsonProperty
public String getFullName() {
  return firstName + " " + lastName;
}

@JsonIgnore
public void setFullName(String fullName) {
  // Empty method
}
```

Having an empty setter does not make a lot of sense, in my opinion. But maybe my assumption to have an attribute transfered without having a property representing it, was wrong in the first place!?

Answer (score 1):

Use `JsonIgnoreProperties` annotation:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Person {
```

From documentation:

> Property that defines whether it is ok to just ignore any unrecognized
>   properties during deserialization. If true, all properties that are
>   unrecognized -- that is, there are no setters or creators that accept
>   them -- are ignored without warnings (although handlers for unknown
>   properties, if any, will still be called) without exception. 
>   **Does not have any effect on serialization.**

See also:

- [Jackson derived property with getter only gives com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55164244/jackson-derived-property-with-getter-only-gives-com-fasterxml-jackson-databind-e)
- [JsonIgnoreProperties](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnoreProperties.html#ignoreUnknown())